# How to add css media type dynamically to a page

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, printing

I am stuck with a problem to print only gantt chart (or for example a table)from my web application.

I have a web application having a gantt chart in which we are doing scheduling stuff.
now my requirement is I just want to have gannt chart to be print when i gave print command.
I tried the following code in my page style tag:

```css
<style type="text/css">

@media print {
  body * {
    visibility: hidden;
  }
  #content-container , .divGcBody {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
........}
```

```html
<div class="divGcBody">
    <div class="divGcBodySection">
        <div class="divGcColumns"></div>
        <!-- end of divGcColumns -->
        <div class="divGcTimeline">
            <div class="divHCDispList">
                <div class="divTmlnRows divSlider"></div>
            </div>
            <!-- end of divHCDispList -->
        </div>
        <!-- end of divGcTimeline -->
    </div>
</div>
```

but as the gantt getting generated dynamically at run time and this solution does not work and its give me only whatever define in .jsp file.

please let me know how can I only print my gantt out of my whole application.
* that gantt(or table) getting generated at runtime

Comment: All the elements who are inside of the body can't be visible.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this javascript function combined with css (js uses jQuery):

```
function printOnlyGantt() {
            var actualWidth = $('#myGantt').width();
            $('body').prepend($('#myGantt'));
            $('#myGantt').addClass("myScreenshot").css('width',actualWidth);
            $('body>*').css('display', 'none').css('visibility','visible');
         }
    });
```

CSS:

```
body {
 display: block !important;
}

.myScreenshot {
 position: absolute;
 left:0px;
 top: 0px;
}

body>*{
  visibility:hidden;
}

.myScreenshot:first-child{
  display: initial !important;
}
```

To work well you have to open your page in another tab or add a custom class to body while print your diagram and remove that class after that.

This code is tested and works pretty well even if I use it on saved-in-local pages

Comment: it does not worked for me..my whole page got blanked..i think it my mistake Ill modify my question: the thing is I wanted to print a div having scroll bar (horizontal and vertical both) and want to print using window.print() even those part which are not getting display or render on page (the srollable portion).

Comment: my function has to work due to the fact that copy and element (and his children) in top of the page and hide all others, so you'll be able to print your page. Of course virtual space of the page it's hard to manage by yourself but don't make confusion between what have to be a programmer matter (to isolate and choose what to print) and what is a Browser print option. That's why website like Groupon uses PDF to render virtual space: they first select HTML dom elements then translate all over a PDF. And print (on paper or a file) a pdf it's an user task.

Comment: BTW in your case send to send to a printer also the virtual space of your page directly from js means you restrict all elements by a factor that allows all elements to be in a single-sheet. IMHO not a your taks but I don't know what you have to realize ;)